# Unexpected identifier: import axios from './lib/axios.js';, require('axios')

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, axios

I have this `js` file:

**test.js**:

```
const axios = require('axios');

console.log('test');
```

I have installed dependencies by running

```
npm install
```

My folder structure looks like this:

```
test
  node_modules
  package.json
  package-lock.json
  test.js
```

If I remove the first line `const axios = require('axios');`, and run:

```
nodejs test.js
```

it runs fine and prints `test`.

However if the first line is present, I get this error:

```
/home/username/test/node_modules/axios/index.js:1
import axios from './lib/axios.js';
       ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

How do I fix it?

PS

```
node -v
v18.4.0

nodejs -v
v10.19.0

npm -v
8.12.1
```

Comment: What version of Node.js are you using?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

What worked for me:

1. Install **curl**:

`sudo apt install curl`

2. Install **NVM**:

`sudo curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/install.sh | bash`

```
export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm.
```

3. List all node versions:

`nvm list`

4. Select a node **version** to use

`nvm use v19.0.0`

5. Run the file using:

`node test.js`

Comment: The `node` command already runs Node.js version 18 which properly supports ECMAScript modules. Installing yet another version is pointless.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> nodejs test.js
> ```

> ```
>  nodejs -v
>  v10.19.0
> ```

You are running this with Node 10 which is beyond end of life and does not support ECMAScript modules (with provide `import`) except as an experimental feature locked behind a flag.

Use the other version of Node.js you have installed instead.

Comment: I managed to run it using `node scraper.js`. `node -v` is now `19.0.0` and `nodejs -v` is still `v10.19.0`. Why is it so? `nvm` doesn't update `nodejs`, but only `node`?

Comment: `nvm` installs Node.js with a binary named `node`. It doesn’t install a binary named `nodejs`.

Answer (score 1):

For cases where something went wrong when trying to import a module into a custom or legacy environment, you can try importing the module package directly:

```js
const axios = require('axios/dist/browser/axios.cjs'); // browser commonJS bundle (ES2017)
// const axios = require('axios/dist/node/axios.cjs'); // node commonJS bundle (ES2017)
```

ref
https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#installing

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you're using at least Node@12.0.0
2. Change your run command from `node test.js` to `node test.js --input-type=module` (This will allow using `import` in your code)

See the docs: https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#--input-type-flag